# Point, but not line, in plotly.line_mapbox

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I am new to Python so there is probably an easy answer, but I am trying to figure out why I cannot get a line to draw between gps points on mapbox using plotly.  I have two datasets, one a df of oil and gas wells and one is user generated gps coordinates for oil and gas pipeline.  The user generated data is written to a csv file with its only columns being Leg, Lat and Lon.  Data is read for both sets from csv and then well data is displayed in scatter graph and pipeline should be via line graph.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Add NM Well data in scatterbox with wellname, type and PLSS segment
fig1 = px.scatter_mapbox(oil_wells, lat="latitude", lon="longitude", color="type", hover_name='name', hover_data=["ulstr", "id"])

#Add pipeline in line
fig2 = px.line_mapbox(pipeline, lat="Lat", lon="Lon", color="Leg")

#Combine plots

fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)

fig3.update_layout(mapbox_style="white-bg",
                  mapbox_layers=[
                      {
                          "below": 'traces',
                          "sourcetype": "raster",
                          "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
                          "source": [
                              "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
                          ]
                      }],
                  mapbox_zoom=12,
                  mapbox_center_lat = 32.1233832, mapbox_center_lon = -103.62026)
                      
fig3.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
    
fig3.show()
```

Points will show for all coordinates and mapbox legend will show a line based on Leg, but will not draw a line between points.   The line graph code was based upon https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/ which actually prints lines based on only single sets of gps coords.

I have tried setting line thickness and changing the line_mapbox instruction.  I have tried, but been unable to come up with a code that would add the Lat, Lon from each successive line of the csv file as End_Lat and End_Lon to the prior line on the basis that maybe mapbox is looking for both starting and end points.  That doesn't seem to be required based on the csv data in the plotly website sample, which only has individual points

Comment: Your question requires test data that can be used to verify the situation. That is the quickest way to get an answer.

Comment: Leg Lat Lon
1 32.312072 -103.465664
2 32.312054 -103.466744
3 32.310579 -103.466764
4 32.310582 -103.467885
5 32.310024 -103.46788